# Count number of different values within a column, starting from a fixed cell, ending at last cell that has a value in it

Tags: excel, vba

The task is to count the number of different values (suppliers) inside a column, starting at a fixed cell.

Let's say for column A to start at A5, but end at the last cell with a value in that column. Every time I try to put the range from A5 to the last cell with a value in column A I either get errors or a wrong answer.

This is the code I used before, searching values from A5 to A50 and subtracting all the bold headlines. I also added a -1 as an empty cell counts as a value as well I guess or at least I got the right numbers this way.

```vb
Sub Count_Values_()

Sheets("Präsentation").Select

Dim dblAnz As Double
Dim rngRange As Range, rngRangeCnt As Range

Set rngRange = Range("A5:A50")

For Each rngRangeCnt In rngRange
    dblAnz = dblAnz + 1 / WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rngRange, rngRangeCnt.Text)
Next

Dim Bereich  As Range
Dim Zelle    As Range
Dim lAnzahl  As Long

Set Bereich = Range("A5:A50")
   
For Each Zelle In Bereich
    If Zelle.Font.Bold = True Then
        lAnzahl = lAnzahl + 1
    End If
Next Zelle

Sheets("Anleitung").Select

Range("F1").Value = dblAnz - lAnzahl - 1

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Please, try the next way:

```
Sub testCountDefinedRange()
   Dim sh As Worksheet, startRow As Long
   Const searchVal As Double = 25.13 'what is it to be searched for
   
   Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here the sheet you need
   startRow = 5         'the starting row of the range to be searched

   Debug.Print WorksheetFunction.CountIf(sh.Range("A" & startRow, sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp)), searchVal)
End Sub
```

But according to community spirit, you should prove your involvement in solving the problem by your own. Even if you cannot show us a working piece of code/formula etc. Anything proving that you did something, at least, some research on the internet...

Comment: Oh okay, i´ll see if the solution you sent solves my problem thank you very much.

Comment: How can i  open a field to implement code the way you did? I´d like to show you me previous solution for the problem.

Comment: @Sketchy I cannot get you... Now understanding what you mean. You may take `searchVal` from wherever you want/have it...

Comment: In the 3rd line, what exactly does the 25.13 mean and what do I have to replace it with?